# How to create a User based Website supported by a Database

Tags: database, database-schema, development-environment

I have experience developing in MS Access and some Java programming with Adobe Flash Builder.

I would like to create a website where a user can sign in and share and post things similar to Facebook, i.e a social network. I would like to know what is the best program for developing a website (for someone who does not come from an html background) and what is the best database to support this type of website i.e ( Oracle, Mysql ... )

If you have any advice or input please let me know. All advice is effective for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user based website should be implemented both at the front end and the back-end of the application. Components such as username, login, and other information should be obtained upon sign in in order to implement a user-based website. The back end of the site should be on a production server that consists of both php and a sql server system of some sort.